# Sidekiq spawns more workers than it set in config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I have a strange situation with sidekiq. My config file is:

```
---
development:
  :concurrency: 10
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 35

:queues:
  - [default, 3]
  - [very_low, 1]
```

I am working in `staging` environment atm. In my processes I see:

```
 % ps ax | grep sidekiq
 2784 ?        S      0:00 runsv sidekiq
 6206 ?        Sl     3:42 sidekiq 2.17.8 application [10 of 10 busy]
```

So it uses 10 workers as it set in config... or not? In my admin-side I see this:

[image]

My DatafeedUnzipWorker calls DatafeedImagesCreatorWorker, could it be related? Why it shows 30+ workers spawned in back-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those, who experiencing the same issue, [the sidekiq owner replied following](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2093):

> The data gets out of sync if your Sidekiq process crashes or if Redis has networking problems.
>
> The Busy count and Workers tab is notoriously unreliable in 2.x. That's why a heartbeat was added in 3.x. **The answer is to upgrade to 3.x.**